# Pandas: Fill NaN Values row by row by group ID

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I'm trying to fill NaN values row by row according to group ID.

I've tried using fillNA, using the forward and backward fill options, but the fillNA function does not fill up the dataframe row by row. Additionally, I want to make sure that the companies match before the NaN values are filled. In this case, using a forward fill will cause company "Pear" to be filled with data from company "Banana".

```py
appended = appended.sort_values(by=['Company','Intro'],na_position='last')
appended = appended.reset_index(drop=True)

for i in appended.index:

    if i==0:
        pass
    else:
        if appended.at[i,'Company']==appended.at[i-1,'Company']:
            appended.fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
        else:
            pass
```

appended dataframe

```
Company    Intro          Categories         Headquarters  Founded Date   Funding Stage

 Apple       xyz       Healthcare, Big Data     New York       2018           Series A

 Apple       NaN              NaN                NaN           NaN             NaN

 Apple       NaN              NaN                NaN           NaN             NaN

 Banana     Lier           Government           Europe        2010           Series B

 Pear        NaN              NaN                NaN           NaN             NaN
```

This is the expected result that I hope to achieve:

```
Expected Result

Company    Intro          Categories         Headquarters  Founded Date   Funding Stage

 Apple       xyz       Healthcare, Big Data     New York       2018           Series A

 Apple       xyz       Healthcare, Big Data     New York       2018           Series A

 Apple       xyz       Healthcare, Big Data     New York       2018           Series A

 Banana      Lier        Government             Europe        2010           Series B

 Pear         NaN              NaN                NaN           NaN             NaN
```

Comment: Is NaaN just a typo of NaN or something different? oO

Comment: @meissner_ Sorry it was a typo of NaN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)

```
df.groupby(['Company']).ffill()

  Company Intro            Categories Headquarters  Founded Date Funding Stage
0   Apple   xyz  Healthcare, Big Data     New York        2018.0      Series A
1   Apple   xyz  Healthcare, Big Data     New York        2018.0      Series A
2   Apple   xyz  Healthcare, Big Data     New York        2018.0      Series A
3  Banana  Lier            Government       Europe        2010.0      Series B
4    Pear   NaN                   NaN          NaN           NaN           NaN
```

Comment: This is not working for me. The return value of this statement does not contain the complete dataframe.

Comment: Side note: to create / change a single column based on this, you can simply set `df['Founded Date'] = df.groupby(['Company']).ffill()['Founded Date']`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# sample data
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO("""
Company    Intro                 Categories   Headquarters  Founded_Date   Funding_Stage
 Apple       xyz       Healthcare, Big Data     New York       2018           Series A
 Apple       NaN              NaN                NaN           NaN             NaN
 Apple       NaN              NaN                NaN           NaN             NaN
 Banana     Lier           Government           Europe        2010           Series B
 Pear        NaN              NaN                NaN           NaN             NaN"""), header=1)


# Create the summary level - assumes repeat data comes first
df_summary = df.groupby("Company").head(1)

# Join the result
df_result = df[['Company']].merge(df_summary, on="Company")

#  Company Intro            Categories Headquarters  Founded_Date Funding_Stage
#0   Apple   xyz  Healthcare, Big Data     New York        2018.0      Series A
#1   Apple   xyz  Healthcare, Big Data     New York        2018.0      Series A
#2   Apple   xyz  Healthcare, Big Data     New York        2018.0      Series A
#3  Banana  Lier            Government       Europe        2010.0      Series B
#4    Pear   NaN                   NaN          NaN           NaN           NaN
```